(org mode) How to cycle through sparse trees?
I love org sparse trees, but in order to pick a sparse tree I have to press C-c / and then interact some more.
I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut to cycle through sparse-tree views, the way Shift-Tab cycles through expanded/minimal views.
I'm imagining a custom list of sparse tree configurations for the current document, where each of those specify a sparse-tree view (which you'd normally search with C-c / ...). Maybe something like this at the top of the document:
#+SPARSE-TREES: SparseSearch1 SparseSearch2 SparseSearch3
#+CURRENT-SPARSE-TREE: SparseSearch2

And then you can cycle through those three with Ctrl-Tab, which shows the next sparse-tree, and edits the CURRENT-SPARSE-TREE entry (analogous to shifting the todo-state of a headline). Is there anything like this?

What do you mean by sparse tree configurations? A sparse tree is defined by a search ("the subtree of nodes that satisfy some conditions") and is unique for that search.

@NickD, yes sorry, by configuration I meant a specification for such a search. Basically I'm imagining you write down a list of such specifications in the top of the document, see my question.

So you mean precompute and cache each such tree, so you can restrict to it on demand? Nothing like that exists: you'd have to re-execute the search (minibuffer history can help with that: it caches the things that you type in the minibuffer).

@NickD, I don't mean to precompute and cache. I'm just looking for a kind of keyboard shortcut together with some data stored in the .org file specifying the list of sparse-tree-searches to cycle through. I'd want it to recompute the tree each time.

OK - you should probably add your last comment to the question to clarify it (comments are mostly for us to ask clarifying questions of you).
